# XSL: Remove Parent node with duplicate children

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a question about removing parent nodes based on their child nodes.

The XML File has following structure:

```
<PlmXmlData xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:plm="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:an="">
  <ItemList>
    <Item>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Group>Group1</Group>
      <Projekt>Projekt1</Projekt>
      <DatasetList>
        <Dataset>
          <Name>Name1</Name>
          <Type>TXT</Type>
          <Template>None</Template>
          <RelativeFilePath>FilePath1</RelativeFilePath>
          <PropertyList>
            <Property>
              <Title>item_name</Title>
              <Value>ITEM_Name</Value>
            </Property>
            <Property>
              <Title>item_name</Title>
              <Value>ITEM_Name</Value>
            </Property>
          </PropertyList>
        </Dataset>
        <Dataset>
          <Name>Name1</Name>
          <Type>PDF</Type>
          <Template>Template1</Template>
          <RelativeFilePath>FilePath1/Name1.pdf</RelativeFilePath>
          <PropertyList>
            <Property>
              <Title>item_name</Title>
              <Value>CAR1</Value>
            </Property>
            <Property>
              <Title>item_name</Title>
              <Value>CAR1</Value>
            </Property>
            <Property>
              <Title>item_name2</Title>
              <Value>CAR2</Value>
            </Property>
            <Property>
              <Title>item_name2</Title>
              <Value>CAR2</Value>
            </Property>
          </PropertyList>
        </Dataset>
      </DatasetList>
    </Item>
  </ItemList>
</PlmXmlData>
```

As you can see there are different `<Type>` nodes in this example TXT and PDF. 
Within this nodes there are nodes `<Property>` and child nodes `<Title>` and `<Value>`.

I would like to remove the whole `<Property>` node with its child nodes `<Title>` and `<Value>` for each duplicate entry in each `<Type>`.

The desired output should be like this:

```
<PlmXmlData xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:plm="http://www.plmxml.org/Schemas/PLMXMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:an="">
  <ItemList>
    <Item>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Group>Group1</Group>
      <Projekt>Projekt1</Projekt>
      <DatasetList>
        <Dataset>
          <Name>Name1</Name>
          <Type>TXT</Type>
          <Template>None</Template>
          <RelativeFilePath>FilePath1</RelativeFilePath>
          <PropertyList>
            <Property>
              <Title>item_name</Title>
              <Value>ITEM_Name</Value>
            </Property>
          </PropertyList>
        </Dataset>
        <Dataset>
          <Name>Name1</Name>
          <Type>PDF</Type>
          <Template>Template1</Template>
          <RelativeFilePath>FilePath1/Name1.pdf</RelativeFilePath>
          <PropertyList>
            <Property>
              <Title>item_name</Title>
              <Value>CAR1</Value>
            </Property>
            <Property>
              <Title>item_name2</Title>
              <Value>CAR2</Value>
            </Property>
          </PropertyList>
        </Dataset>
      </DatasetList>
    </Item>
  </ItemList>
```

I have searched the forums but could'nt find a fitting solution. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Please select either XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 - not both. To remove duplicates, do a search for *grouping* - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in XSLT 1.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="property" match="Property" use="concat(generate-id(parent::*), Title, '|', Value)" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PropertyList">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Property[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('property', concat(generate-id(parent::*), Title, '|', Value))[1])]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It uses a technique called "Muenchian grouping", which uses the `key` function to find matches over the XMl for a certain condition, then checks if the current context is the same as that first match, to ignore duplicates. The equality check uses the `generate-id` function; each XML element has an id attribute, either explicitly or implicitly generated at run-time, that uniquely identifies it.

In our case, the key matches `<Property>` elements and indexes them. Because we want to remove duplicates within a `<PropertyList>` and not across the whole XML, the key uses an "index": a concatenation of the (generated) if of the parent `<PropertyList>`, the `<Title>` element value, the `|` symbol and the `<Value>` element value. That's what this part does:

```
<xsl:key name="property" match="Property" use="concat(generate-id(parent::*), Title, '|', Value)" />
```

The template that matches `<PropertyList>` then recursively applies templates, but only for `<Property>` elements where this predicate holds: `[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('property', concat(generate-id(parent::*), Title, '|', Value))[1])]`

Let's break that down. `generate-id(.)` generates an id for the current node (the Property element). It then checks if that id is the same as the one generated for this: `key('property', concat(generate-id(parent::*), Title, '|', Value))[1]`

That says "the key named property, for the match on the concatenation of the generated id of the parent (our PropertyList), Title, `|` and Value" and then takes only the first element of the matched node set.

Note that you said this:

> As you can see there are different  nodes in this example TXT and PDF. Within this nodes there are nodes  and child nodes  and .

I assumed that each type (TXT, PDF, ...) occurs only once in a given `<DatasetList>` and that you want to remove duplicates local to a `PropertyList`. If the types could be repeated and you want to remove duplicates across the whole type, you'd have to take the Muenchian grouping to another level (include the type). But I figure the above solution is what you were aiming for.

Also, this could potentially fail if the Title and Value elements may contain `|` symbols. You could choose a different separator in that case.

If you can use XSLT 2 this becomes a whole lot simpler because it has grouping built in. In that case, specify in your question and I could make a new answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I tried your method and it works so far except that it removes the Tags `<PropertyList>` and `<PropertyList/>`. How can I keep those elements in the file?

Edit: Just added the tags! Thank you!

Comment: @M4rk0444 Oops, you're right. The template matches PropertyList but then goes straight to handling the Property elements without copying the current node. I'll edit the XSLT right now to fix that.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot!